# Can a body be in thermal equilibrium at a different temperature from surroundings?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation, radiation, equilibrium

As per my knowledge bodies attain constant temperature (thermal equilibrium with surroundings) when they absorb and emit energy at equal rates.

Let us say temperature of surroundings is T1.

We have a large collection of bodies at a temp T2 (different from T1) with equal emmisivities and with different coefficient of absorption (absorptivity), say for example a=0.001, a=0.002 .... a=0.999

Energy emitted by each body would depend on T2 and e only and will be equal for all bodies

Now we put those bodies in surroundings one at a time and see if it
is possible for some value of $a$ that energy emitted by one of those bodies is equal to energy absorbed by that same body? (even though we already know that T1 and T2 are different)

Explanation in layman's terms would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario includes thermal interactions between many objects at $T_2$.  If those are the only interactions you are interested in, then we can say the system is at equilibrium.  Stating that the surroundings are at $T_1$ is only meaningful if there is an interaction between the surroundings and at least one object.  Unless one has perfect insulation (which does not exist in nature), there will indeed be some interaction with the surroundings at $T_1$, and you will find the system is not at equilibrium.  The objects that are interacting with the surroundings will change temperature, leading to non-equilibrium interactions between all objects until eventually they reach equilibrium at $T_1$.

There are some times where approximating the system as being "perfectly insulated" from the surroundings is reasonable.  In these cases, we would say the system was *approximately* at equilibrium at $T_2$, and admit that we were ignoring effects that would show that it isn't actually at equilibrium.

Comment: I am sorry, I believe my question was a bit unclear, I have edited it